# REGEX - Limit only numbers in a string, but allow any number of other specific characters

Tags: regex, validation, phone-number

I currently have this: `^\+?[()\d -]{6,12}`

It allows a leading +, allows ()-  characters, and numbers. But the total length of the string is limited to 6-12 characters.

I want to achieve the following:

- The length limit only applies to the numeric characters. Any number of the other special characters is allowed

**valid**:

```
123456  
+123456  
+(12) (2)3-5-2
```

**invalid**:

```
1234  
1 2 (3) 4  
1233451231231
```

Comment: What is your programming language?  What can achieved with a long ugly regex can also be achieved with just 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: You seem to be very lenient in how you describe your requirements. In fact, you just seem to want to validate 6-12 digits and you are not concerned about the positioning of the other characters. If that is true, then try: [`^\+?(?:[-() ]*\d){6,12}[-() ]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jrRJ1s/1). I can however see your list of requirements grow from here....

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm limited to a tool where true codding cannot be used, regex however can

Comment: @JvdV thanks, the suggestion works well for me, I adjusted it mildly to only allow a single plus sign in the front, and it's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^\+?(?:[()\h-]*\d[()\h-]*){6,12}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vwCnDQ/1)

Explanation:

- `^` - Start of string
- `\+?` - Matches optional plus character
- `(?:[()\h-]*\d[()\h-]*)` - This basically matches zero or more your non-digits allowed characters followed by a single digit then again followed by zero or more your non-digits allowed characters
- `{6,12}` allows above text minimum six and maximum 12 times
- `$` - End of string

You haven't mentioned regex dialect, hence if `\h` (horizontal space) is not supported, then you can use normal space or use `\s`